# CCFollow and ParallaxNode works wierd

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I'm newbie, trying to integrate a CCsprite to follow one layer of parallaxnode.
It suppose to follow the bg04 sprite.
It turns out....., yes, it follows, but on the opposite direction.

Here is the code, please help, thanks!

```
-(void) addParaBG
{


CCSprite* bg01 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Page001bg01.png"];
CCSprite* bg02 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Page001bg02.png"];
CCSprite* bg03 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Page001bg03.png"];
CCSprite* bg04 = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"Page001bg04.png"];

bg01.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
bg02.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
bg03.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
bg04.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);

bg01.tag = 01;
bg02.tag = 02;
bg03.tag = 03;
bg04.tag = 04;

CCParallaxNode* paraBG = [CCParallaxNode node];
[paraBG addChild:bg01 z:1 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(1, 0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[paraBG addChild:bg02 z:2 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(2, 0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[paraBG addChild:bg03 z:3 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(3, 0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];
[paraBG addChild:bg04 z:4 parallaxRatio:CGPointMake(4, 0) positionOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)];

[self addChild:paraBG z:0 tag:paraBGtag];
}

-(void) moveParaBG
{
CCMoveBy* move1 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:15 position:CGPointMake(-160, 0)];
CCMoveBy* move2 = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:15 position:CGPointMake(160, 0)];
CCSequence* sequence = [CCSequence actions:move1, move2, nil];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:sequence];

[[self getChildByTag:paraBGtag] runAction:repeat];
}

-(void) addAnimationElement
{
CGSize screenSize = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];
CCSprite* testship = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"ship.png"];
testship.position = CGPointMake(screenSize.width /2, screenSize.height /2);
[self addChild:testship];

CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFile:@"ship-anim" frameCount:5 delay:0.08f];
CCAnimate* animate = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim];
CCRepeatForever* repeat = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:animate];

[testship runAction:repeat];
[testship runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:[[self getChildByTag:paraBGtag] getChildByTag:04]]];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using CCFollow backwards. The background layer runs the follow action on the sprite, not the other way around.

So:

```
[testship runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:[[self getChildByTag:paraBGtag] getChildByTag:04]]];
```

Should be changed to:

```
CCSprite *bg = (CCSprite*)[[self getChildByTag:paraBGtag] getChildByTag:04]];
[bg runAction:[CCFollow actionWithTarget:testship]];
```